# Equation. $x^4+4x^3+3x^2+2x+1=0 $

Tags: polynomials

Is there method to solve the following equation:

$$x^4+4x^3+3x^2+2x+1=0 ?$$

thanks for your help, it seems impossible for me.

Comment: Wikipedia can talk you through the process of solving a quartic equation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function .  The roots in this case are rather ugly, as WolframAlpha shows (using "Exact Forms"): http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%2B4+x%5E3%2B3x%5E2%2B2x%2B1

Comment: All in the span of 2 minutes, 3 peoples thought process on how to answer this question was to link to the same Wikipedia page, and Wolfram Alpha's output. lol.

Comment: @RagibZaman: "LOL" perhaps, but it's becoming "SOP". :)  ... (That's "Standard Operating Procedure", by the way.)

Comment: @Amzoti: That link is in error (it's solving a cubic). [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[x^4+%2B+4x^3+%2B+3x^2+%2B+2x+%2B+1+%3D%3D0%2C+x]) is probably what you wanted.

Comment: @robjohn: fat fingers again on my part! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inspection it seems there will be no rational roots [(by rational root theorem)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). At x=0 there is no root, and for x>0 the given polynomial is always increasing so there will be no positive roots either. From here we are likely stuck in trying to get an approximate, rather than exact answer.

The solution to the general quartic equation has been posted already which will provide an exact answer (including complex valued roots) but this is a long and in my opinion relatively useless tool unless you're truly desperate for exact answers. We could attempt something along the lines of a [bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to get closer and closer guesses for possible answers.

Another tool which may or may not be in your arsenal is [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) which requires some basic calculus. The simplest approach of all is probably to put it into wolfram alpha if an actual numerical answer is needed. Otherwise one of the above methods may be put to use.

However, these approximation methods require good guesses as to a neighborhood of your domain where a root could be; this is not always an easy task and you may overlook some possible roots. Neither will these methods give you complex valued answers (if such an answer is needed).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to [solve it exactly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation) but it is a real mess.  You can send it to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E4%2b4x%5E3%2b3x%5E2%2b2x%2b1=0) and get approximate roots.  Without Alpha, most people would go for a numeric solution.  There are root finders discussed in any numerical analysis text.